# Programmatically pass data to MatMenuTrigger

Tags: angular, typescript

I understand how to open a `mat-menu` from from typescript. My problem is normally data would be passed by `[matMenuTriggerData]="{ data: input }"` and received by `matMenuContent` within the HTML. This is what I've tried:

```
@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) private menuTrigger: MatMenuTrigger;
```

...

```
this.menuTrigger.menuData = this.data[i];
this.menuTrigger.openMenu();
```

when debugging `menuData` is set correctly but once the menu opens the data received is undefined

```
// Child Component
@Input('data')
public set dataInput(data)
{
    this.value = data.Value; <--- error
}
```

The page has many triggers that open the same menu with different data. Once one menu is open the user should be able to go to the next or previous menu which is why I need to be able to do it from typescript.

**HTML:**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let input of this.formInputs[base64data.index]">
    <area [matMenuTriggerFor]="editMatMenu" [matMenuTriggerData]="{ data: input }" shape="rect" [attr.data-name]="input.Name" [attr.coords]="input.Rect" />
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was thinking about this the wrong way. Since I already have many triggers with the right data attached, I simply needed to open the correct trigger.

```
@ViewChildren(MatMenuTrigger) private menuTriggers: QueryList<MatMenuTrigger>;
```

Then I iterated through the triggers until I got the one with the right `menuData.data`

```
for (let i: number = this.menuTriggers.toArray().length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (this.menuTriggers.toArray()[i].menuData.data.Name == this.currentInput.Name)
    {
        triggerIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

I also found a way to do it completely from the ts with a click handler

```
public openMenu(input): void
{
    this.menuTrigger.menuData = { data: input };
    this.menuTrigger.openMenu();
}
```

instead of

```
[matMenuTriggerData]="{ data: input }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `[matMenuTriggerData]` directive is already added in your component, then placing a variable to bind to the HTML element will just work fine.

ie. in your .ts file

```js
this.menuData = this.data[i];
```

and in your html file

```html
<input [matMenuTriggerData]="menuData"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately in this situation I need to do both. The trigger needs to go off when clicking on an element and once the menu is open I have events that open the next or previous menu.